# Schreibweise: Open-Source-Software

Tags: spelling

Welche Bindestrichschreibweisen sind richtig?
Der [Duden sagt dazu eigentlich](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Schreibung-von-Fremdwortern-aus-dem-Englischen), dass es *Open-Source-Software* heißen muss. Allerdings kann man auch argumentieren, dass *Open-Source* das eingedeutschte Adjektiv ist und man folglich *Open-Source Software* schreiben kann. Immerhin ist auch *quelloffene Software* richtig.

Comment: _Open-Source_ ist kein Adjektiv. Es ist weder deklinierbar noch steigerbar.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, wer das Wort *quelloffen* benutzt, aber es klingt ziemlich konstruiert und nicht sehr gebräuchlich.

Comment: _Open-Source_ ist die englische Version von _quelloffen_. Und _quelloffen_ wird durchaus verwendet, s. linguee.com

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Was ist an *quelloffen* nicht deklinier- oder steigerbar? Steigerungen von Adjektiven müssen nicht unbedingt sinnvoll sein, siehe "schwangerer"

Comment: @tofro Über _quelloffen_, was sehr wohl ein Adjektiv ist, habe ich überhaupt nichts geschrieben, sondern über _Open-Source_. Und das ist – ich wiederhole mich – kein Adjektiv, auch kein eingedeutschtes. Sonst müsste es nämlich deutsche Deklinationsendungen tragen, wie etwa: männlich _ein open-source(ne)r Computer_, sächlich _ein open-source(ne)s Betriebssystem_ und weiblich _eine open-source(ne) Software_.

Comment: Es würde auch kleingeschrieben, außer am Satzanfang. Du schreibst ja auch nicht Quell-Offene Software.

Comment: *open* ist ein Adjektiv, *source* ein Nomen. Du müsstest *Open-Source-Software* also genau wie »Hoher-Meißner-Straße« oder »Hi(gh)-Fi(delity)-Anlage« schreiben.

Comment: @Raketenolli Auch wenn Ihre Schlussfolgerung richtig ist: Ihre Annahme ist falsch. Zwar ist _open_ ein **englisches** Adjektiv und _source_ ein **englisches** Nomen, aber im Deutschen sind sie es eben nicht. Sonst müsste man _open_ deklinieren und _source_ großschreiben. Bitte vermischen Sie nicht die englische Grammatik mit der deutschen.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich: Auch wenn ich Open-Source selbst nicht für ein Adjektiv gehalten hätte, so ist fehlende Deklinier- und Steigerbarkeit kein hinreichender Grund dies auszuschließen. Auf der Seite https://www.cafe-lingua.de/deutsche-grammatik/deklination-der-adjektive.php heißt es: *Neben dem Großteil der deklinierbaren Adjektive gibt es auch solche, die nicht deklinierbar sind. Diese stammen in der Regel aus anderen Sprachen oder es sind Adjektive, die Farben darstellen.* *Open-Source* würde in die erste Gruppe passen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nach den Regelempfehlungen des [Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/regeln-und-woerterverzeichnis/) gelten hier folgende Regeln:

> **§ 45 E1:** Aus anderen Sprachen stammende Verbindungen aus Substantiv + Substantiv, die sich im Deutschen grammatisch wie Zusammensetzungen verhalten, werden zusammengeschrieben; ebenso ist die verdeutlichende Schreibung mit Bindestrich möglich: Sexappeal (Sex-Appeal), Sciencefiction (Science-Fiction), Shoppingcenter (Shopping-Center), Desktoppublishing (Desktop-Publishing), Midlifecrisis (Midlife-Crisis)

Im Sprachgebrauch, wie er durch die diversen Wörterbücher abgebildet wird, hat sich die Schreibung ***Open-Source-Software*** gegenüber *Opensourcesoftware* durchgesetzt. Das gilt auch für andere Zusammensetzungen wie z.B.: *Open-Source-Projekt, Open-Source-Entwickler, Open-Source-Fan*.

> **§ 37 E4:** Aus dem Englischen stammende Bildungen aus Adjektiv + Substantiv können zusammengeschrieben werden, wenn der Hauptakzent auf dem ersten Bestandteil liegt, also Hotdog oder Hot Dog, Softdrink oder Soft Drink, aber nur High Society, Electronic Banking oder New Economy.

Das heißt, dass man hier ohne Bindestriche, aber groß, schreibt, also *Opensource* oder *Open Source*. Im Wörterverzeichnis ist dies nicht direkt aufgeführt, man kann aber schon annehmen, dass hier eine gleiche Empfehlung wie bei *Open End* und *Open Air* gilt.

Also können folgende Beispielsätze gebildet werden:

> - Bei Salamandra hingegen handelt es sich um Open-Source-Software, die jedermann kostenlos herunterladen und modifizieren kann. <sup>Die Zeit 27.12.2017</sup>
> - Open Source steht für Transparenz, für Offenheit – und für Leidenschaft. <sup>Die Zeit 4.6.2018</sup>

---

*Anmerkung:* Da dies nur Regelempfehlungen sind, wird man immer wieder auch andere Schreibweisen finden. Eine adjektivische Verwendung als *open-source* kommt nicht in Frage, weil bei einer solchen Zusammensetzung das Nomen nicht am Ende stehen kann (es müßte dann *source-open* heißen, was es aber nicht gibt).

Comment: Danke, ich denke auch, dass _Open Source_ alleine stehend so geschrieben werden kann.

Comment: Es lässt sich nicht leugnen dass sich das Isoliertschreiben solcher Begriffe immer mehr verbreitet. Es lässt sich aber auch nicht leugnen, dass es dem Deutschen uneigentlich ist und nur wegen der US-amerikanischen Kulturdominanz so invasiv auftritt. Leider spielen auch deutsche Kulturinstitutionen mit, etwa wenn sie sich *Leibniz Universität Hannover* nennen statt deutsch und bieder *Leibniz-Universität Hannover*. Mit überraschend gutem Beispiel und ganz ohne Scheu vor dem traditionellen Bindestrich geht allerdings die *Ada-und-Theodor-Lessing-Volkshochschule Hannover* voran.

Comment: Doch, das lässt sich leugnen. Ich beobachte, dass die Neigung bei neuen Fremdwörtern hoch ist, Leerzeichen zu verwenden, bevor Bindestriche verwendet werden, um dann schließlich bei Zusammenschreibung zu enden - es dauert nur Jahrzehnte.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Auch die [Ludwig-Maximilians-Universität München](https://www.uni-muenchen.de/index.html), die den Bindestrich sogar in ihrem Logo aufführt.

Answer (score 4):

Verschiedene Quellen sind sich einig, dass man

> Open-Source-Soft­ware

schreibt.

So hat der Duden nicht nur den in der Frage genannten Übersichtsartikel, sondern einen eigenen Artikel für das Wort [Open-Source-Soft­ware](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Open_Source_Software).

Aber auch canoo.net hat einen Eintrag [Open-Source-Soft­ware](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=open-source-software&service=canooNet).

Der Rechtschreibrat befasst sich bei Fragen und Antworten mit dem Thema, [wie man englische Wörter schreibt, die nicht im Wörterbuch stehen](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/service/fragen-und-antworten/). Dort ist es allerdings nicht explizit genannt. Zur Unterstützung kann man den letzten Absatz heranziehen, der mehrere Beispiele von Durchkoppelungen, bei denen deutsche und englische Wörter kombiniert werden, aufzeigt. Das ist aber im vorliegenden Fall wiederum diskussionswürdig, weil natürlich die Frage ist, ob "Software" nun ein englisches oder ein deutsches Wort ist (vergleiche die Diskussionen in den Kommentaren, die als Alternative "quelloffene Software" nennen).